# Zxing does not support arm64

Tags: ios8, xcode6, qr-code, zxing

Anyone has any idea for ZXing Arm64 ?

QRCode scanning process become slow in iOS 8 devices.

Please give the steps to make **ZXing arm64 compatible** or also guide the **steps to include it in XCode 6.0.1.**

Answer (score 1):

For me, it is also very slowly, but in iOS 7+ we can use built in QR/bar code scanner.